# Using JmsTemplate directly with Camel routes

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Can Spring JmsTemplate directly (not as Camel classes which extend Spring classes) be used with Apache Camel routes? If yes, are there good examples using Java configuration?

There is an Spring configuration based example - https://dzone.com/articles/apache-camel-spring-routing-0

How is the CamelContext is connected to the JmsTemplate in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah if you mean using pure Spring JmsTemplate java code, then you can from its MessageListener, call Camel routes via Camel's `ProducerTemplate` / `FluentProducerTemplate`.

In fact you can always use/call Camel that way.

Since you are using Spring (or maybe Spring Boot) then you can setup Camel via Spring dependecy injection.

Comment: Yeah calling camel from AWS lambda using the ProducerTemplate.

Comment: Thank you! But that is still using ProducerTemplate. Is there any example where we can do this without using ProducerTemplate at all, only Spring Boot classes?